# output markdown in r code chunk

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a R markdown file that I want to output rmarkdown from the script itself. For example, I would have the following simple code in an Rmd file.

````
---
title: "test"
author: "johndoe"
date: "September 5, 2015"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r cars}
paste("## This is a Heading in Code")
summary(cars)
```
````

I want "This is a Heading in Code" to render in rmarkdown. There is a solution in an R script to generate markdown as per http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/r_notebook_format.html. But I am trying to figure out how to do this in a Rmarkdown file. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There is a simple answer to inject html directly into the code. For example to replace paste with `cat("<h2> This is a Heading in Code </h2>")` and set the chunk options to `results="asis"`. This will work but then you lose the markup formatting for the summary(cars). I want to output the markdown syntax, have it be rendered and also output the summary(cars) in the markdown format.

Comment: Use two different code chunks with the solution suggested in your comment.

Comment: ah yes... thank you. duh. that is correct. I will answer my own question and then write another question for what I really want to do.

Comment: but then again... the problem is that I won't be able to output to the other markdown formats and have to use html.

Comment: Don't use `<h2>` skipping ahead to HTML. Use `##` and go to markdown. Pandoc can still handle any conversion then. You also don't have to use `cat`, just have your code chunk be `print("## My heading")`.

Comment: The approach of using `results="asis"` with markdown inside `cat()` works well also for non html outputs. However,  contrary to @GregorThomas `print()`  does not work for me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Why build the header markup (either in markdown or HTML) manually? Try inline R expressions or some helper functions in `pander` (to generate markdown programatically):

````
---
title: "test"
author: "johndoe"
date: "September 5, 2015"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## `r 'This is a Heading in Code'`

```{r title, results='asis'}
library(pander)
pandoc.header("This is a Heading in Code", level = 2)
```

```{r cars, results='asis'}
summary(cars)
```
````

Comment: thanks. dumb question. this code block isn't running for me in rstudio. can't find the function pandoc.header.

Comment: pandoc.* functions are perfect.

Answer (score 5):

I searched for a good answer for this for some time after using `cat("## Heading")` inside `results='asis'` code chucks. I have seen many people dissatisfied by the `results='asis'` setting in the code chunk because it sets **all** results of the code chunk to not be wrapped in a code markup block. We have many cases when we want to output the heading along with results that should be wrapped in markup (e.g. a kable table that renders to a html table).

Here is the solution I found by simply specifying the "asis" attribute to the text object with `knitr::asis_output` and keeping the code chunk in the default `'markup'` setting.

````
---
title: "test"
author: "johndoe"
date: "September 5, 2015"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r cars}
knitr::asis_output("## This is a Heading in Code")
summary(cars)
knitr::kable(summary(cars))
```
````

[image]

Unfortunately, at the current time `knitr::asis_output` only works in top-level R expressions, and it will not work when it is called inside another expression, such as a for-loop.