# How to generate rmarkdown chunk within a chunk

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, bookdown

I'm trying to generate a `rmarkdown` chunk using code. I've read similar questions and their solutions, such as using [pander](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32420266/934898) or using `cat`. I just can't seem to generate it. I also tried knitting the output manually. Here's an example of a `Rmd` file:

````
---
title: "test"
output: pdf_document
---


## R Markdown

```{r, results='asis',echo=FALSE}
txt <- paste("```{r}",
      "2+2",
      "```")
pander::pander(txt)
```
````

When I `knit` this, I get a verbatim `{r} 2+2`. I would like to see the number four instead. In my real example, I'm using `bookdown` and trying to generate a `block2` chunk.

Any ideas how to generate this chunk that gets evaluated as `R` code?

Comment: I don't understand. Why don't you just evaluate 2 + 2 in a chunk, or inline? And what is `block2`?

Comment: because the point is not to evaluate 2+2. The point is to be able to evaluate the whole chunk later. block2 in bookdown lets you create your own environments. I've a call out box with computed stats as well as some text formatting. And when I put all of that in the block2 chunk, knitr spits it out it verbatim.

Answer (score 2):

Does this do what you want?

````
## R Markdown
```{r, results='asis',echo=FALSE}
txt <- paste("```{r}",
      2+2,
      "```")
pander::pander(txt)
```
````

This evalutates to

````
```{r} 4 ```
````

in your markdown document.
You using a string literal `"2+2"` as opposed to the expression `2+2`. This is the first issue, I guess.

If you want it correctly parsed you need to add an `sep = "\n"` argument to `paste` *or* manually add the newline breaks. 
I.e.

````
## R Markdown
```{r, results='asis',echo=FALSE}
txt <- paste("```{r}\n",
      2+2,
      "\n```", sep = "")
pander::pander(txt)
```
````

This evalutates to

````
```{r} 
4
```
````

which is interpreted as R code in the markdown document.

Comment: I would like to see just plain number 4 as the output of the chunk and not the r markup. That 2+2 could be a function or anything that I would like to be evaluated later.

Comment: I've already edited the post :). You also need newline breaks to have the backtics on their own lines.

Comment: ah. that works. in this case, you don't even need pander, you could simply cat. I will try this on my complex example.

Comment: No, you're right it is not needed in this toy example. I just thought it might be in your real case.

Comment: so, I tried this in boodown and it works partially. so if the engine is r, python or even block2 in the generated markup, the chunk gets evaluated properly and the output is correct. But when I add a type to the block2 engine, it prints the engine verbatim. Here's link to blocks in bookdown: https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/custom-blocks.html

Comment: I'm not familiar with block2 (or block). You reference mentions that the implementation is a hack (so unexpected behavior might follow) and that "if the last element in the block is not an ordinary paragraph, you must leave a blank line at the end". So have you tried adding an extra `"\n"` before the ending backticks to ensure this? I.e. `"\n\n```", sep = "")`